# First Questions/First Answers/Late Answers reviewers should be partially or fully exempt from the suggested edit queue size

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

The suggested edit queue has a maximum size, which is supposed to make sure edits are getting reviewed at a rate which can be managed by the available reviewers. This queue size is the same for all users that are less than 2k reputation.

However, since this queue is full more often than it is not, it is a real annoyance while reviewing first questions. The purpose of the first questions queue is for us to review and help new users. When I click `Edit` instead of `Looks OK` or `Share feedback`, and then improve the question, just to find out that I will have to keep going back until the queue is no longer full, it makes reviewing a much more tedious process.

I want to review first questions and improve them, but edits being blocked 3/4 of the time kills my motivation.

I suggest that either:

- There is a number of slots in the Suggested Edits queue reserved for suggestions submitted via First Questions/First Answers/Late Answers review.
- Suggestions submitted via First Questions/First Answers/Late Answers review are exempt from the cap.

Comment: To clarify some terminology, the queue size isn't "the same for users below 2k", edits by users above 2k are _exempt_ from the queue. See: [edit posts - privilege awarded at 2k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) | There's a single, unified queue for all suggested edits, regardless of user reputation (there's also a per-user cap for total pending suggested edits as well, but this isn't a "queue" really, just a limit).

Comment: @zcoop98 That's right, that's what I meant.

Comment: We should just get rid of the extremely low cap on the suggested edits queue. It's silly.

Comment: @TylerH That too.

Comment: Remove the cap and we'll be able to get a better idea on how many suggested edits *actually* need to get reviewed daily and possibly do something to reach that goal rather than playing whack-a-mole

Comment: @KevinB Another thought is this cap seems inherently ineffective. When a suggested edit is blocked because queue full, either; the user will give up and discard their edit, this wasting the time they spent writing the edit, or; the user will wait until the queue is no longer full, so the edits are still in a phantom 'queue' of edits waiting to be submitted after edits waiting to be reviewed. Either way, the user is more annoyed and has spent time dealing with this. The site should not be designed to waste people's time.

Comment: eh, a recent change kinda fixed that. Edits in-progress are no longer blocked from being sent.

Comment: @KevinB Are you sure? In review queues, the edit page works, and when I click Submit, it is still blocked. Or if the review queue becomes full while I am still editing, it is still blocked.

Comment: Decreasing number of pending edits to one probably would be better solution, or even one-a-day/one-a-week for someone else posts. The number of reviews is known, so it should be somewhat easy to figure out how many reviews should be allowed in the first place... Or maybe bounty on edits :) ?

Comment: @user16217248 at least intent is to allow edits in progress to be excluded from the cap... So far feature broke all edit-your-own posts, I'd not be surprised if they forgot to check edits from review queue flows...

Comment: Yea the i'd call that new feature not working in review queues a bug