# Allow <2000-rep users to bypass the queue limit when suggesting edits in review queues, or don't allow them to review in queues with an edit option

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Users with less than 2000 reputation [have access to four review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues): First questions / answers, Late answers, and Triage. All of them except Triage have an *Edit* option.

During review in these queues, many questions do seem fine ("*Looks OK*") and most of the review is just about clicking this option.

Yet, some questions / answers obviously need an edit, e.g. using code snippet on a non-web language instead of code block.

Without 2000 reputation, if you are not trying to farm review badges, and you actually review diligently with the goal of improving posts that need edits (rather than simply marking everything "*Looks OK*", or doing some other review action that doesn't improve the post, like downvoting/flagging and moving on), you may get stuck for hours in "*The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!*"

This totally breaks the review queue pace for sub-2000 reputation members and forces us to just click "*Looks OK*" or "*Skip*", which does not really add up to what review queue is meant for.

---

#### Suggestion / feature request

The following two proposals are mutually exclusive options:

- Make an exemption to the suggested edit queue limit for edits made from review queues. I don't care about edits on some random posts, but the limit is a problem that impacts other review queues.
- Grant the privilege to do reviews in queues where editing is an option only after 2000 reputation, when [the privilege to edit posts without review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) is granted, so that nothing prevents a proper review. Otherwise, reviewers below 2000 reputation may just skip the edit option.

Finally, in my humble opinion, being granted a free edit after reaching 2000 reputation does not really make sense. Yes, 2000 reputation might be considered as being mature on Stack Overflow, but one can also get those with some popular questions, not really dedicating themselves to editing. It would be more sensible to grant a free edit option after reaching some number of approved edits.

---

I cannot call myself proud of my [22 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8489602/dimithras?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but the problem is, if I do reviews and do edits, there are times I don't submit them because of the edit queue being full. That's work that could improve the site being totally lost.

I've also heard it suggested that, due to the possibility of achieving up to 1,000 reputation from having edits approved, this won't be a problem for long.  However, given the long time required for edits to be approved and the difficulty of even submitting them to the queue in the first place, this would take an *extremely* long time.

Comment: Maybe the system is just not designed for <2k rep users to perform reviews that could require suggested edits...?

Comment: [Why doesn't SO block the edit option if the edit queue is already full and why can't we have a read access to the edit queue in review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416102/why-doesnt-so-block-the-edit-option-if-the-edit-queue-is-already-full-and-why-c) [First Questions/First Answers/Late Answers reviewers should be partially or fully exempt from the suggested edit queue size](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423499/first-questions-first-answers-late-answers-reviewers-should-be-partially-or-full)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I guess so… It would make sense to give access to review queue the same time edits are unlocked, IMHO. Otherwise it forces to escape doing edits.

Comment: Yep, that's the exact reason why I don't do Reviews, I was "happy" to contribute when I had reached 500-Rep, but I quickly gave up because of that "Edit workflow" for <2k-Rep Users... (Although Edits (to 'First Questions') might now be a little less needed, thanks to the 'Staging Ground', I would think...)

Comment: @chivracq the only viable option that remains is Triage, that does not put a spoke in the wheel. The fun fact, I'm seeing users with 9x Steward medals who are <2000 pts, do they just put "*Looks OK*" on everything?

Comment: Given you are able to earn 1,000 reputation from approved edit proposals, doing so make it very easy, to earn the required reputation allowing to you to transition to ultimately becoming a trusted editor thus no longer requiring your edit proposals to be reviewed by other members of the community.  The current reputation requirement is extremely generous, I would argue, it's to low if users are spamming "Looks Ok" instead of actually reviewing and selecting the **correct** review action.  I see far to many people become review suspended, because they fail to properly, review a contribution.

Comment: @SecurityHound this will require 500 edits, as one approved edit grants 2 points, not to mention that some of them will not be approved. Points are earned mainly by answers and questions. And btw, one could have an ultra popular question not doing any edits, get 2000+ pts and become a trusted editor. That's another flaw, as trusted editor should be granted for approved edits, IMHO.

Comment: @DiMithras - 500 edits is a very low bar to accomplish to earn 1,000 reputation which is half of the requirement.  If a user can't get edit proposals to pass, then they are likely, not proposing edits that should be done in the first place.  I review at least a hundred edit proposals a week, I see a lot of proposals, that are incomplete or actually introduce additional grammatical errors into the contribution.

Comment: @SecurityHound yet getting points with edits is a hard way, especially given the limit.

Comment: @SecurityHound, "*Given you are able to earn 1,000 reputation from approved edit proposals, doing so make it very easy, to earn the required reputation*", yeah, easy to say, knowing that *we* (<2k-Rep) first need 24h before finding a "free spot" in the "the Edit Queue is full, try again later", then another 48h before our Edit will eventually get approved.  [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] => We already need 1500 days (= 4 years!) (OK, could be shortened to 502 days if we make a "full time job" 24/7 from suggesting Edits) before getting those +1000 Rep from 500 suggested Edits. But in those 3 days, those mostly badly formatted/full of typos/grammar mistakes Questions by 1-Rep Users will often have gathered some Downvotes, and will end up being roomba'd 9/30 days later, ... and we re-lose those 2Pts Rep from our "approved Edit" again. Catch 22...!

Comment: @DiMithras -  I had no problem earning the reputation from edit proposals. Here is a suggestion, don't polish contributions, that will be roomba'd. It's hard to earn reputation from edit proposals when you have only made 24 in over 2 years.

Comment: @user thanks for the edit! Do you mean the second one on the list? It would make sense in regard that users would still be able to do edits, but will not have the hassle during reviews. From my own experience I had to reach 1000 pts on ruSO to fully understand if and how I should mark reviews / put flags / edits, being a newbie I was over engaged. That's my own experience anyway and ruSO is not that active, if the queues are overpopulated, they should not be limited to 2000 pts for sure. As for the feature-request link, I totally agree, that could lessen the load of edit queues.

Comment: I extensively edited the post to try to get all the responses to clarification requests into a shorter version of the post.  I also cleaned up the comments a bunch, including fixing a typo in a comment ("approving" → "approved" in @SecurityHound's comment) and removing some responses that were based on that typo.  If anyone thinks I removed anything important that isn't captured somehow, let me know.

Comment: It would make more sense to make reputation actually mean reputation. There should be caps on how much reputation a single source awards, so that reputation correlates with a sustained, long-term effort for the community; not mere occasional luck. However, I'm not sure the problem is [considered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321816/should-users-be-rewarded-with-privileges-reputation-from-very-little-contribution) [sufficiently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259887) [significant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256717/users-that-live-off-of-old-questions).

Comment: "It would be more sensible to grant a free edit option after reaching some number of approved edits." Related on MSE: [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Probably even more related: [Opining a successful-edit-count-based two tier suggested edit system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387434/1241222)

Answer (score 10):

I remember not too long ago when I had <2000 rep and was reviewing *First questions*. I completely agree that it is a nuisance to be restricted in queues to which you've already gained access.

However, I have to take a stronger position on this: <2000 rep users should have full edit privileges when reviewing. It doesn't make sense to clutter the *Suggested edits* queue with reviews arising from other queues.

And I'd argue there's precedence for this too. In the *Low quality answers* queue, <20k rep users can "Recommend Deletion", which is nearly the same as voting to delete, except only within the queue. Only new posts appear in the 500 rep queues, so it wouldn't be possible for a review to mess up an important post or abuse the limited privileges.

Comment: Yep exactly...! Reaching 500-Rep "now" (=2023) takes a few years after joining the Site... Such Users (500-Rep) then have a pretty good understanding on how the Site works and what is the "minimal quality level" expected for Questions, especially from 1st time Askers. Once getting 500-Rep, "we" get access to a few Queues, and want to contribute back, the 'First Questions' Queue is the "most logical" Queue to help with, 90% there need some Editing (basic formatting/full of typos/grammar mistakes/most Users don't know that x2 Spaces are needed for a 'Return'), but we can't even really help...

Comment: "_And I'd argue there's precedence for this too. In the LQA queue, <20k rep users can "Recommend Deletion"_" keyword "**recommend**". There's a similar word in our edit system: "suggest". oh look! it's already like that.

Comment: @user Suggested edits alone though can't do anything, they need to be approved. On the other hand, recommended deletion reviews can lead to the deletion of an answer without review by >25k rep users.

Comment: then follow that actual precedent: propose to allow reviewers in the 500-rep queues review one anothers' suggested edits on items in those queues. that's actually not a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>(converting my comment to an answer for better visibility / to elaborate a little)</sup>

> Make an exemption to the suggested edit queue limit for edits made from review queues. I don't care about edits on some random posts, but the limit is a problem that impacts other review queues.

The problem I see with what you're suggesting is that the problem with the edit queue is the rate items move through it. What you're suggesting faces the same problem with suggestions to just increase the item capacity: It doesn't do anything to change the rate at which items move through the queue: It doesn't further incentivize edit reviewers to review edit suggestions, it doesn't change how many reviews each item requires, it doesn't change the expiry period of suggested edits, and it doesn't do anything to make it easier to review suggested edits. I really question how doing what you suggest will address that deeper problem.

I'd take a more general approach to the problem of full edit queues. See my proposal on MSE: [For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383823/997587).

That would make edits by people who have shown they are recently, consistently good at making good edits go through the edit queue faster, which should have some knock-on effect of making the edit queue move faster in general, though that doesn't necessarily mean you'll have better chances at the queue not being full when you want to suggest an edit, since we're already so saturated in the influx.

There's another possibility worth exploring and discussing: Allowing reviewers in the 500-rep queues to review each others' edits, which apparently has some precedent based on how in the Low Quality Answers queue, users without deletion privileges can recommend deletion, and enough such reviews can actually result in deletion of the post.

> Grant the privilege to do reviews in queues where editing is an option only after 2000 reputation, when the privilege to edit posts without review is granted, so that nothing prevents a proper review. Otherwise, reviewers below 2000 pts may just skip the edit option.

I'm really not a fan of this idea. My first reaction to it is concern and an assumption that it's only there as a strawman. A big part of the whole problem here is not enough reviewers (in the edit queue).

Taking more reviewers out of other queues is just creating another problem, no?

Do you realize that except for the Triage queue, all the other queues unlocked at 500 rep have an edit option? First Questions in particular is just always totally swamped.

Comment: I would say that in general, the main problem here is that SO conflates expertise in a domain, participation, and moderation abilities. A more general solution would be to decorrelate those, and let moderation abilities be gained by demonstrating good moderation instincts. In this case, getting edit privileges by having a history of (overall) good edit suggestions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. see also JourneymanGeeks' [Opining a successful-edit-count-based two tier suggested edit system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387434/997587).

Comment: @MatthieuM. indeed, that's one of my main points. Getting edit privilege does not really sound, especially if one does not do any edits by the time he / she reaches that milestone. Same goes for review queues, I feel like it's totally okay if newbies help with first questions / answers, but triage seems to be one level above.

Comment: @user we've discussed earlier, but again, I totally agree with the second point comment. If review queues are floodded and there aren't many members working on them, limiting review queues will result in those being even worse. But, as **MatthieuM.** suggested, there should be some ranking system for reviewers.